# "sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra" acts differently in CentOS 7 and RHEL 7

Tags: linux, rhel

I have two VMs; one with RHEL 7 nad other with CentOS 7.
Running `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra` show different behaviors on two VMS.

CentOS 7

```
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
```

RHEL7

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra 
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra: No such file or directory
```

Yet, this parameter `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra` exists in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

```
# sysctl settings are defined through files in
# /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
#
# Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
# To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
# /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
# only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
# name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
fs.suid_dumpable = 0 
kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0 
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 1
pv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.core.somaxconn=511
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
```

What can be the reason for the error in RHEL 7?

**Update**

Later I found there is no `ipv6` directory in `/proc/sys/net/`. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: IPv6 is disabled in your *specific* configuration?

Comment: Add the output of `sysctl -a | grep ipv6.*disable` as root on both VMs to your question.

Comment: Hi Nasir, nothing returned

Comment: try this instead: `grep ipv6 /proc/cmdline`

Comment: `# grep ipv6 /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/osvg-root ro ipv6.disable=1 LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

@A.B:  So, ipv6 is disabled, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 has been disabled *at boot* on your system. When it's done like this, there's no remaining trace of IPv6 available at all.

Usually this is done by adding an option in `/etc/default/grub`.

If that's the case, you can revert this setting by editing `/etc/default/grub` and removing the option `ipv6.disable=1` which should be present in the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and then running:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

to regenerate the GRUB options with your changes.

A reboot is then required.